# How can i handle shared_ptr ++

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, shared-ptr

```
 int main ()
 {
    shared_ptr<int[]> a(new int[2]);

    a.get()[0] = 5;
    a.get()[1] = 10;

    int* foo = a.get();

    ++foo;

    cout << *foo << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is "10" as i expected. But I used regular pointer (int* foo) how can i implement/use ++ operator with only shared_ptr.

Comment: At first: `shared_ptr<int[]> a(new int[2]);`.

Comment: If you have a `shared_ptr` pointing inside an array (instead of the first element) I guess bad things will happen when this pointer tries to free it's content.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. If you have a simple (non-smart) pointer, e.g. `int* foo = new int[2];`, then doing `foo++` will loose the original pointer, which is bad.

Comment: And what is your use-case for using the array variant of `std::shared_ptr`? Why not use a `std::vector` instead? What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to "increment" the smart pointer?

Comment: I think it's bad but i try write my iterator class and private data member of my iterator class is  shared_ptr<T> foo so i threw an example like this

Comment: If you have written your own container and are creating iterator for it, then consider this: It makes no sense to iterate over a container if the contained data disappear. Therefore I would say it's okay to have a `std::unique_ptr` inside the container for the ownership of the data, and then your iterators could use plain simple non-owning (non-smart) pointers which could easily be incremented or decremented as needed. If the container is destructed and the user keeps an iterator then it's the fault of the user, and not something you should (or, realistically, can) prevent.

Comment: If You are writing Your own container, please have a look at the functionality of [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). There You will find things like `begin()`  which returns an iterator to the first element. Or `at(...)` which returns an element at a specific index. It is a bad idea to mix the functionality of a container and an iterator into 1 object.

Comment: Won't Adding a proxy class/function over `shared_ptr` help?

Answer (score 1):

A `std::shared_ptr` contains two parts:

1. A pointer to the bookkeeping.
2. A payload-pointer which should be valid at least as long.

So, for your pointer-arithmetic, just use a dependent `shared_ptr` [setting both individually](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
shared_ptr<int[]> foo(a, a.get() + 1);
```

As an aside, an array-`shared_ptr` supports indexing, so no need to go over `.get()` for that.

Also, as long as you keep one `shared_ptr` aroud to keep the data live, there is nothing wrong (actually, it is expected and more efficient) with using raw pointers and references for processing.

Answer (score 0):

***There isn't another way.***

The only method is to call get and the increment it in the copy returned from the get.

I attach you some usefull link :

[smartpointer - shared_ptr](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared.const)

[cppreference.com - shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is semantically meaningless. A shared_ptr expresses the intent to **own** something (in this case an array of two int's). All it does is track ownership. If you increment a shared_ptr, does that mean you release the ownership of the first int? Or does it mean you own the second int twice? Either way is not what you are trying to do.
In general, use unique_ptr/shared_ptr only for ownership issues. To manipulate and use the memory directly, use a view class, something like a [span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). Not all compilers have this facility yet, so may have to use either the [GSL library](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guideline-the-guidelines-support-library) or write your own. However you implement it, it is better to make a separate object that views the object, but does not claim to own it. If you can tie the length of the array to pointer, this is better still.